# "TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "float") to tuple"

Tags: python

I am writing a program to open and read a txt file and go through loops each line. multiply values in 2nd column and 4th column and assign it to 5th column.

```
A 500.00 A 84.15  ?

B 648.80 B 77.61  ?

C 342.23 B 39.00  ?
```

this is part of codes I wrote,

```
for line in infile:
    a,b,c,d = line.split()
    e = eval(b) + eval(d)

    print("{0:20}${1:20}{2:20}${3:20}{4:20}".format(a,b,c,d,e),file=outfile)
```

I kept getting an error saying,

> File "C:/Users/hee lim/Desktop/readfile2.py", line 19, in main
>       e = eval(b) + eval(d)
>   TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "float") to tuple

I covert strings into numbers using "eval" to multiply those numbers. 
I don't understand why it flags an error.

thank you for your help.

Comment: Page your full code please.

Comment: @TilakMadichetti I believe you mean _paste_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at this information, I could only tell that the value returned by `eval` of `b` and `d` are of `float` and `tuple` type. And you can not do `+` on `float` and `tuple`. For example:

```
>>> 5.0 + (2 ,3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'tuple'
```

For debugging, add `print line` at the start of `for` loop to see at what value it is raising error.

Comment: thank you so much!!!, as I went to debug using your code, I found out that there is one typo "1,400.00" in my original txt file, python recognized it as a tuple..

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got this error because I incorrectly removed an index in my for loop trying to enumerate.

Before (no error)
`for i, item in enumerate(items):`

After (error)
`for item in enumerate(items):`